# How to use the same SSH alias with multiple host addresses/ports/etc.?

Tags: ssh, alias, openssh

Here's the problem: I'm trying to SSH into a system that is accessible from at least 3 different networks—sometimes directly, sometimes via a proxy—at different times.

Connecting directly is far faster and more reliable than connecting via an intermediate host, which is again far faster and more reliable than connecting over the general internet, so I would like SSH to attempt to connect in 3 different ways in a prioritized fashion, picking the first that succeeds.

They're all the same machine, obviously, so I don't want to keep having to manually choose between 3 different aliases depending on where I'm connecting from.

However, I can't find any mechanism for solving this. Is it possible to do this at all, or no?

If not, what do people generally do in such a situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use aliases for `ssh` connections! Use a proper `ssh_config` in `~/.ssh/config`. It has some truly powerful features.

Lets say you can identify in which network you are. For example using your IP, which can be pulled for example using `hostname -I`. So lets write some configuration:

```
# in network1 I am getting ip from "10.168.*.*" and I need to connect through proxy
Match Host myalias Exec "hostname -I | grep 10\.168\."
  Hostname real-host-IP
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy-server

# in network2 I am getting IP from "192.168.*.*" and I do not need a proxy
Match Host myalias Exec "hostname -I | grep 192\.168\."
  Hostname real-host-IP

# in network3 I am getting something else
```

Comment: YES! Thank you!! I'd lost hope but this is exactly what I needed! My line looks like `Match Host myalias Exec "hostname | xargs nslookup | tail -n +5 | grep -q -e '^Address:\s*192\.168\.1\.'"`, for any readers wondering.

Comment: Maybe something changed but I had to double-quote the command: `Exec "hostname -I..."`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747254).

Comment: @spawn probably yes. I think I wrote it mostly as a pseudocode to give the point. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You can store a shell alias or a function in your `.bashrc` or whatever else is your shell's config file. For example, for a Bash alias:

```
alias my_ssh="
ssh mehrdad@"IP1 ||
ssh tomas@IP2 ||
ssh tomas@IP3
"
```

Then call the alias:

```
 my_ssh
```

And if IP1 fails, `||` makes the second command execute. And so it goes again, now with the IP3.

I've not tested this, but it should be ok. Or at least shows a way.

For SSH options like proxies, see `man ssh`.

Comment: The problem here is dealing with the timeouts.

Comment: Great point by @RuiFRibeiro. Also the other problem is that I'm not asking for a shell scripting tutorial. I'm asking *if there's a way to make the `ssh` command do this*. As in, I want to be able to SSH into this server the same way I SSH into any other server. A generic script that uses SSH will completely fail on this machine if it has to call a different command.

Comment: BTW it's not enough to use ```||``` because ssh exits with the return value of the last remote command. You need to check for exit code 255 to be sure that there was a connection problem.

Comment: @rudimeier Actually in my testing it seems like exit code 255 isn't the only bad exit code ssh gives.  Depending on why it was failing I was getting a few different codes.  https://support2.microfocus.com/techdocs/2487.html

Comment: Also there is `ssh -o ConnectTimeout` depending on what version of ssh you are running.  I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @rush Yes I had tested this using *openssh* client: ```ssh localhost 'exit 123'; echo $?``` prints 123. It's documented in the man page: *ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.*

Comment: @rudimeier my bad. I completely forgot that I have an alias to use autossh instead of ssh. it has different behaviour on exit statues. sorry for confusion.

Comment: I still got an exit code in the 100s while I was trying to ssh to made up hosts and/or known hosts with made up usernames at some point.  Could have been me because I'm only seeing 255 now as well.

Answer (score 1):

This function may work, but if Tomas's alias works I think that's a better solution.

```
autossh () {

  publicip="11.11.11.11"
  privateip="10.10.10.100"
  proxyhost="10.10.10.10"
  proxyport="9001"
  ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $1@$privateip 2> /dev/null && exit 0
  if [ $? -ge 1 ]; then
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $1@$publicip -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x $proxyhost:$proxyport %h %p" 2> /dev/null && exit 0
    if [ $? -ge 1 ]; then
      ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $1@$publicip 2> /dev/null && exit 0
      if [ $? -ge 1 ]; then
        echo "I think your node is down"
      fi
    fi
  fi

}
```

Comment: Thanks but this misses the point of my question... see my comment under his answer.

Comment: Alright well what you're asking is still vague then, but the way I understand it; the short answer is no.  Long answer is rename my function or Tomas's alias to `ssh`.

Comment: Your function might have an unexpected behaviour in case already established ssh session got accidental disconnect.

Comment: What do you mean?  The `$?` will only represent the last executed command so if an ssh session terminated before running the function it's exit code would be overwritten before the function tries to ssh.

Comment: @Jesse_b I mean that if ssh connection to $1@$privateip will be successfully established but it will unexpectedly die afterwards, the exit status will be non-zero and the function will try to connect to public ip instead of simply dying.

Comment: Ah, True.  Would `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $1@$privateip 2> /dev/null && exit 0` work?

Comment: well. it doesn't really differ from the previous way :) `&& exit 0` will be triggered only in case ssh is completed with 0 exit status which is covered by `$? -ge 1` anyway.

Comment: Yea I didn't even think that lol...duh.  Oh well I'm sure it can be fixed but may not be an issue, usually when my ssh exits with error I wouldn't mind if it automatically retried anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several solutions, some better than other, and ignoring security implications, or infra-structure (unknown) limitations:

- doing an SSH reverse tunnel (an ugly hack);
- setting up anycast with the help of OSPF or BGP, and sshing to a anycast VIP;
- the remote machine establishing an IPsec tunnel - without the proxy;
- communicating via Tor
- updating a site/page/Redis/MySQL server with the current address, and your ssh script fetching it;
- using HAProxy;
- dynamic DNS.

Comment: Some of these suggestions seem absolutely ridiculous... communicating via Tor? Using Redis? Makes me wonder if you've even understood the point of the question...

Comment: I would advise some concepts of networks and what is anycast. I am not giving an extensive list of *good* solution, my point is more about showing there can be a lot solutions once you get creative. And I also find it absolutely an excellent policy using the word ridiculous with people helping you for free.

Comment: Are you doing a bingo? I bet this is the first time on all the StackExchange sites that an answer uses OSPF, Redis and HAProxy in less that 500 lines. Add RS-485 and iSCSI and you get my vote ;-)